# PuTTY gives different result when running remote command vs SSH command-line

Tags: ssh, putty, vncserver, tightvnc

In Windows 10, from the command line when I run

```
ssh grant@xyz.com vncserver -localhost
```

everything works fine. But when I try to run the same command in a graphical PuTTY interface by entering the same `grant@xyz.com` for the hostname and `vncserver -localhost` as the remote command, it still runs, but it doesn't run the same way and must be doing so in a different environment. What is even stranger, when I run PuTTY on the command line with

```
putty -ssh grant@xyz.com -pw foobar-m "command.txt"
```

where `command.txt` has the text `vncserver -localhost`, it runs correctly!

In short, does anyone know how running a remote command in the graphical PuTTY interface differs from running a remote command with either ssh or PuTTY from the command line? This has been annoying me for hours, I want to make the set up for the end user as simple as possible, and I feel as though there is just a simple setting to change. Thanks!

PS: If you know anything about Xvnc (with TightVNC as the frontend), the issue is the xstartup script will not run when I use the graphical PuTTY interface but does run when I use any other method. This is to provide background on my specific issue in case it helps.

PPS: To note, no, that is not my real password and I use SSH keys for authentication.

Comment: What happens if you run `putty grant@xyz.com vncserver -localhost`, and what happens if you run `ssh -t grant@xyz.com vncserver -localhost`?

Comment: `putty grant@xyz.com vncserver -localhost` unknown option "-localhost"
`ssh -t grant@xyz.com vncserver -localhost` recreated the undesirable behavior with Xvnc. Checked box in PuTTY "Don't allocate a psuedo-terminal" and it's now working great! I'll be honest I'm not familiar with psuedo-terminals, so thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that by default, the graphical PuTTY interface uses a pseudo-terminal. Under Connection, under SSH, under TTY, when I checked the box "Don't allocate a psuedo-terminal", it works fine.

Comment: Probably *all* SSH clients ask the server to allocate a pty when they're connecting in "interactive" mode – it allows remote programs to use job control (fg/bg) or to handle the interrupt keys (Ctrl+c) – and many things use the presence of a terminal to detect whether they also should run in "interactive" mode, e.g. programs may enable color codes in their output, ~/.bashrc may do more setup, etc. (Pty allocation is usually off by default in "batch" / "single command" mode to avoid interfering with binary output.)